# Avoid find full index needs to be scanned for values unequal to a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want update table `User` and set some values. My current aproach is:

```
UPDATE Users 
SET Maried = 0, 
    Sex = NULL 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Facebook 
             FROM Social 
             WHERE Id = @param 
               AND (CountryId = 16 OR CountryId = 20)) 
  AND ID NOT IN (SELECT Facebook 
                 FROM Contact 
                 WHERE Id <> @param 
                   AND (CountryId = 16 OR CountryId = 20))
```

How should I avoid full scan to able get ids into subquery ?

Comment: What is the definition of all three tables including indexes? What execution plan are you getting?

Comment: `Contact` and `Social` appear to have very similar structures. Is it possible that you've got attribute splitting here and what it ought to be is a single table with an additional column containing the `Contact`/`Social`-ness of the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try splitting the query into two parts and using a temporary table, like below:

```
SELECT Facebook
INTO #temp
FROM
    (SELECT Facebook 
    FROM Social 
    WHERE Id = @param 
        AND (CountryId = 16 OR CountryId = 20)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Facebook 
    FROM Contact 
    WHERE Id <> @param 
        AND (CountryId = 16 OR CountryId = 20) ) reslt

UPDATE u
SET Married = 0
    , Sex = NULL
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN #temp t on u.ID = t.Facebook
```

This might give better performance if you have a few records you need to update. Although you might get even better performance with other approaches, but for that we would need to see an execution plan (**at least**).

And may I suggest, for sharing the execution plan you use [pastetheplan.com](http://pastetheplan.com/)